# extract certain columns in python

Tags: python

I am trying to extract certain columns from my data.

Below is the list of columns that I want to extract: GA02220,GA02230,GA02240,GA02250,GA02260,GA02270,GA02280,GA02290,GA02291

I have write a code which makes me to get column until GA02290 but I can't find a way that I can get GA02291 as well. Can you please help me to find a way to get all the 9 columns?

```
engineCount = 1
cylinderCount = 8
for no in range(engineCount):
    for i in range(cylinderCount[no]):
    engineNo = str(no +1)
cols = ["GA022"+str(i)+'_0'+str(engineNo) for i in range(20, cylinderCount[no]*10+21,10)]
```

Comment: Are you looking for something fancier than `cols = ["GA...10)] + ["GA02291"]`?

Comment: If this is a certain list, why would you need to create it with for loops? Just define a list of `['GA02220', 'GA02230', 'GA02240', 'GA02250', 'GA02260', 'GA02270', 'GA02280', 'GA02290', 'GA02291']`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have 4 different data set and two of data sets have GA02291 but others doesn't so I want to find a way to include GA02291 in cols, not separately or in a loop .

Comment: try using a dict in your case. Something like cols = {'a':['GA02220', ... , 'GA02290'], 'b':['GA02220', ... , 'GA02291'], ...} then  "for dataset in ['a','b','c','d']: col = cols[dataset]"